# Unable to execute .NET HelloWorld sample app on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-iot-core

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 7 with VS 2015 Update 1 and universal applications package installed. I am able to compile the HelloWorld C# sample for ARM from the Windows 10 IoT samples package. I am also able to copy the file (and all assemblies) to my Raspberry Pi2 using the Windows Explorer.

Still I can not run the application on Windows 10 IoT. It says "The system cannot execute the specified program".

I can not run it on my Windows 7 as well (compiled for x86), but I suppose that is because I lack the Windows 10 universal applications runtime. But then it should still work on the Windows 10 IoT.

Just copy/paste shoule work, right?

I also have the "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" enabled in VS.

Comment: Windows 7 is likely not ARM

Comment: When I try on Windows 7 I compile for x86.

Comment: Raspberry? Maybe see [RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/failed-to-start-package-window10-iot/35003#35003)

Comment: Have you checked the requirements? http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your PC to the public release of Windows 10 (version 10.0.10240)

### See all requirements here: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm

Please mark my reply as answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I found is to create an AppPackage (Store package). Then you access the Windows IoT webgui through http://yourwindowsiot:8080. Then you can deploy your package from the "Apps" menu.

Do not forget to add the dependencies. For me these are 3:

```
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2.appx
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1.appx
Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.14.00.appx
```

Tested in release mode.